# mysql regex not returning correct results

Tags: mysql

I have a table called lis_pendens and a table called docket_entries. Each lis_pendens record has many docket_entries, where the foreign key of docket_entries is case_id. If the description field of docket_entries contains the text 'writ' or 'title' or 'sale' or 'dismissal', then I do not want to return the associated lis_penden record in the result set. Otherwise, if none of the docket_entries belonging to a lis_pendnes record contain these keywords, then I want to return the lis_pendens record in the result set.

Here is the query I have created:

```
SELECT lis_pendens.id as id
FROM lis_pendens
INNER JOIN docket_entries
ON docket_entries.case_id = lis_pendens.id
WHERE no_foreclosure_sale_created_at IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM docket_entries AS e
  WHERE e.case_id = lis_pendens.id
  AND LOWER(e.description) REGEXP 'writ|title|sale|dismissal'
) GROUP BY id
```

I thought the query was good but it's producing EVERY lis_pendens record in the database, even though some of those lis_pendens records have associating docket_entries whose description field contains this:

```
Notice of Voluntary Dismissal
Notice of Dismissal & Discharge of Lis Pendens
Certificate of Title
...
```

Obviously, something is wrong with the query. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the data type of the `description` column?  I'm guessing it's a blob type, because binary data doesn't match character data unless the octets are the same, and `LOWER()` doesn't understand how to operate on data that has no character set (as blobs don't).  Try `AND CAST(e.description AS CHAR) REGEXP 'writ|title|sale|dismissal'` ... that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MAX()` to perform a group-wise NAND operation:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM lis_pendens p
INNER JOIN docket_entries e ON e.case_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING MAX(LOWER(e.description) REGEXP 'writ|title|sale|dismissal') = 0;
```